# How do I access model data on Meteor's client side using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, model, meteor, client-side

I'm missing some key Meteor syntax that must be so obvious, I can't track it down.

I have a model called locations with MongoDB data like so:

```
Locations.insert({
    title: "Eridanus",
    body: "Eridanus is a constellation. It is represented as a river; its name is the Ancient Greek name for the Po River.",
    latitude: "32.715",
    longitude: "-117.1625"
});
```

I publish this model:

```
Meteor.publish('allLocations', function() {
  return Locations.find();
});
```

And I can even call this up in a template. My template is called `client/views/locations.html`

```
<template name="locations">
  {{#each locations}}
    <div class="location"><h3>{{title}}</h3></div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

However, I also need to be able to access this location model in the accompanying javascript for this page, which I call `client/views/locations.js` So far I have something like this, but I'm at a loss for how to get the lat long information from my model into object in the javascript.

```
Template.locations.rendered = function () {
  //Psuedo code
  for each location in locations {
    console.log('Logitude', location.longitude)
  }
}
```

What's the proper way to reference the location model that I know is getting published to the client? I've read through the documentation and done a bit of searching but can't track down the answer. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you subscribe to a set of documents, they will reside in your local minimongo database. You can access them them using a cursor, (e.g. using [find](http://docs.meteor.com/#find)). In your example:

```
Template.locations.rendered = function() {
  Locations.find().map(function(location) {
    console.log('Logitude', location.longitude);
  });
};
```

or

```
Template.locations.rendered = function() {
  var locations = Locations.find().fetch();
  _.each(locations, function(location) {
    console.log('Logitude', location.longitude);
  });
};
```

Comment: Ahh yes. Thank you. That is the concept I was missing. I didn't understand the local client MiniMongo instance created by the subscription.

Comment: Well, I spoke too quickly. That's returning totally empty for some reason. I can query the db on the server side with `db.locations.find()` but the locations set returns empty on the client.

Comment: Turns out I had a typo in my router script, causing the Locations object to get goofed up. Your example is perfectly correct. Thanks for putting up with my back and forth.